# Get values from array inside data object using ng Repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to use ng repeat to get values from array

here is my html

```
 <ion-list ng-repeat="item in locationresult">
        <ion-item >
            <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="innerItem in item.loc[$index]">
                <h2>{{innerItem.name}}</h2>
                <p>Income:1334 vs Expences:3742</p>
            </ion-checkbox>

        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

here is my controler

```
  angular.module('starter').controller('locationCtrl', function($scope, $state, userlog, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.init = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            alert(userlog.email);
            document.getElementById("locresult").textContent = "";

            var request = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://expensetracker.linkwebz.com/Home/locationsearch",
                data: {
                    email: userlog.email,
                },
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            });

            /* Check whether the HTTP Request is successful or not. */
            request.success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);

                $scope.locationresult = data;

            });
        });
     };
  });
```

here is  my data object

```
Object { loc: Array[3] }

object
loc:Array[3]
 0:Object
  iduhlocation:"1"
  location_idlocation:"1"
  name:"mark"
  user_iduser:"177" 
 _proto_:Object 
 1:Object
 2:Object
 length:3
 _proto_:Array[0] 
_proto_:Object
```

I tried to repeat  data as  mention above  html  it's  not working  how i  iterate through array  and show all data in html  have idea any one?

Comment: If that data represents full server response you want to loop over `locationresult.loc`. If that is just one item in the response array we would need to see more data structure

Comment: Use just one repeat and set it to: "item in locationresult.loc".  Then you can access the name property on each of your objects with item.name.

Comment: The data object you give represent an item or the locationresult object ?

Comment: –  Yoann   it  represent location result object

Comment: change  repeat   "item in locationresult.loc   is  working  thank you    jme11  and  thank you  every  one  for  help

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one `ng-repeat` if your data is as you have shown as:

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="item in locationresult['loc']">
     <ion-item >
           <ion-checkbox>
               <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
               <p>Income:1334 vs Expences:3742</p>
           </ion-checkbox>
     </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: @Nikini90s you should hit that check mark next to the answer if he solved your problem :)